# when I use this code to resize and upload image yo server get 400 error

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```js
thisUploadImage = async(e) => {
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  const compress = new Compress();
  const resizedImage = await compress.compress([file], {
    size: 2,
    quality: 1,
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxHeight: 300,
    resize: true
  });
  const img = resizedImage[0];
  const base64str = img.data;
  const imgExt = img.ext;;
  const resizedFiile = Compress.convertBase64ToFile(base64str, imgExt);
  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('image', resizedFiile);
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("Token")}`
  };
  axios.post(`url`, fd, {
    headers
  }).then(response => {}).catch(error => {})
}
```

When I use this code to resize and upload image yo server get 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

A `400 status` represents a `Bad Request`, meaning the server can't process the request because of a client error. Make sure you are posting to the correct endpoint in the API and make sure the endpoint can process the object you send to it.

You can check this by comparing the output of `console.log(fd);` to the model your API expects.

Try testing the API with a tool like for example [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), you can read more about `400 status` in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).

Comment: when check output of resizedFiile this give me :
Blob {size: 147310, type: "image/png"}

and when add this output to formdata and send to server get 400 error

Answer (score 0):

```js
let file_name = new File([resizedFiile], file.name, {lastModified: file.lastModified, type: file.type});
```